# lxc-console only works once

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, lxc, tty

I have a debian-squeeze host-system on which I have installed lxc.

i created a (squeeze) container, and started it. then I'm trying to get inside the container with lxc-console. everything works fine so far.

but the weird thing is, lxc-console only works once! meaning: if detach from it (Ctrl+a q) and try to reattach again (lxc-console -n containername) the command prompt never appears. it just says "Type Ctrl+a q to exit the console" but that's it. nothing else - no login prompt

I can exit the console and try to reconnect - but still the same.

the only way to get it to work again is, stopping the container and restarting it again. then I can connect via lxc-console. but again....only ONCE. after the disconnect, I don't see a command prompt anymore....

has anybody seen this kind of behavior before?

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting enter when it does that. It seems to help at least some of the time.